# git clone git@myserver:gitolite-admin fails

Tags: git, gitolite

I am trying to get an git server repository running.
I did install gitolite

when running git info over ssh the server answers

```
ssh git@myserver info

hello Brian, this is git@hepide01pep1 running gitolite3  on git 1.6.3.2
R W   testing
```

When trying to clone the gitolite-admin repository I get the following error

```
git clone git@myserver:gitolite-admin

Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
FATAL: R any gitolite-admin Brian DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Same thing happens with this syntax

```
git clone ssh://git@myserver/gitolite-admin 
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
FATAL: R any gitolite-admin Brian DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Cann anybody give me some useful hints? I checked the Answers here and on the web but didn't find anything that helped me any further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gitolite-admin` is only accessible with the public key named after the git account used for the gitolite server.

You are using by default your `brian.pub`, which only gives you access to `testing.git` repo.

you need to define a `$HOME/.ssh/config` file on your local workstation, in order to record ssh parameters to use the right key.
See "[gitolite: can connect via ssh, can't clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9340778/6309)".

```
~/.ssh/gitolite.pub
~/.ssh/gitolite
```

> Then I define a config file: ~/.ssh/config with in it:

```
host gitolite
     user git # replace it by the actual git user for the gitolite server
     hostname server.com
     identityfile ~/.ssh/gitolite
```

The clone will work:

```
git clone gitolite:gitolite-admin
```

---

The [OP macbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135785/macbert) confirms:

> I did rename the key to `git.pub`, ran `gitolite setup -pk git.pub` and removed the old `brian` key from the `.gitolite/keydir`.
>   After that I got `git clone git@myserver:gitolite-admin`:

```
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'... 
remote: Counting objects: 15, done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done. 
remote: Total 15 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) 
Receiving objects: 100% (15/15), done.
```

So with the right default key, a `ssh git@myserver info` should this time display the right access for `gitolite-admin` repo in the 'hello' message.

Comment: ah good hint - this works

git clone git@myserver:testing.git
Cloning into 'testing'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository. 

how could I change this?
On this guide it looks to my like the key could be named anything:
$ mkdir bin
$ gitolite/install -ln
$ gitolite setup -pk sena.pub
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/gitolite/repositories/gitolite-admin.git/
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/gitolite/repositories/testing.git/
WARNING: /home/gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys missing; creating a new one

Next step would be the clone an the tut. says it works

Comment: @macbert correct: but you won't be able to clone `gitolite-admin` unless you specify through the `config` file that you want to use the right public key. And the name of the keys is important.

Comment: Okay great! I did rename the key to git.pub ran gitolite setup -pk git.pub and removed the old brian key from the .gitolite/keydir

After that I got

git clone git@myserver:gitolite-admin
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
remote: Counting objects: 15, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (15/15), done.

Sound great - Thanks @VonC

Comment: Btw. you should never need to change anything in `.gitolite/` manually. That’s what the `gitolite-admin` repository is for. Whenever you push an update to that repository, it automatically updates. So when you want to rename a user, change the name of the key file *and* update the configuration file to use the new name and commit&push that together. Otherwise it will fail.

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer is a good one if you you're just setting up gitolite, but if you're a new user to an existing installation, you'll get the same error as the one in the question unless you've been added as an administrator.

If you have shell access to the server gitolite lives on, login and switch to the user that gitolite users - usually called `git`.

Once logged into the gitolite user, go to the conf file and give yourself RW+ rights on the gitolite-admin repo. Gitolite conf is usually in `/home/git/.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf` (assuming username is `git`).  For a gitolite user named `Peaches`, grant the permissions thusly:

```
repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   OriginalAdmin Peaches
```

Save the file, and run setup from the command line, still as the gitolite user:

```
gitolite setup
```

If you've been setup as a user correctly, you should be able to clone now.

For more on adding users, see [the documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/users.html)

Comment: Just a note that if you're on ubuntu and you've installed gitolite via apt-get, gitolite setup is 'gl-setup'

Comment: Thanks, this helped me very much! Especially the gitolite setup part!

Answer (score 1):

Usually bare git repos are using a *.git* name. Please try to do

`git clone git@myserver:gitolite-admin.git`

Comment: same output :-7 git clone git@myserver:gitolite-admin.git
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
FATAL: R any gitolite-admin Brian DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: @macbert normal: this has nothing to do with the name of the repo, and everything to do with how gitolite control the access to that specific '`gitolite-admin`' repo.

Comment: Gitolite is smart enough to take care of the `.git`; you don’t need it at all.