# Push to Gitlab returns fatal

Tags: ssh-keys, gitlab

Using a fresh Gitlab install, generated and added SSH keys to the user account, created a new project.

From a local machine, created one (1) folder, added a readme and preformed the following from the terminal:

```
git init
git add README
git commit -m '1_16_2013' 
git remote add origin git@192.168.1.55:root/test.git 
git push -v origin master
```

The push asks for the git@192.168.1.55's password and returns:

```
Connection closed by 192.168.1.55
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Do I need to add a shh key to my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the public and private keys (`id_rsa` and `id_rda.pub`) stored on your `~/.ssh` directory of your local machine.
Otherwise, any ssh to the gitlab server will ask for a password.

You also need to use the right ssh address:

```
git@192.168.1.55:test.git
```

You shouldn't have any path in front of the name of the git repo: gitolite (used by GitLab) will detect the name of the repo and will use the right repo path.

I prefer storing this information (server name, ssh user, private key...) in a `~/.ssh/config` file: see "[gitolite: can connect via ssh, can't clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339272/gitolite-can-connect-via-ssh-cant-clone)" as an example (or "[`git clone git@myserver:gitolite-admin` fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617672/git-clone-gitmyservergitolite-admin-fails)").

Comment: Understood. Added the public and private keys to my ~/.ssh directory of my local machine. I am able to push to Gitlab, but I keep running getting  a response of 'FATAL: W any test admin_local_host DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
'.

Comment: @Harrison check out the gitolite logs. You might have more information there.

Comment: Yup, looks like I need to push to the full path. git@192.168.1.55:root/test.git Do I need to update something to avoid using the full path?

Comment: @Harrison pushing with the full path is never a good idea with gitolite: it usually is a sign that you are bypassing gitolite check (http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/emergencies.html#ce). So your initial path is good, but your gitolite.conf somehow denies the push.

Comment: also as a side... if you have encrypted home directories... you may have to move it to an unencrypted location. i.e. /etc/ssh/username/.ssh/authorized_keys to allow it to be accessible when you're not logged in