# Cannot clone repository: FATAL: R any gitolite-admin gitolite DENIED by fallthru

Tags: linux, gitolite

I'm setting up *gitolite* for first time. I'm following [this instructions](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-8.html).

When I ssh, it looks fine:

```
$ ssh -p 2222 gitolite@debian
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
hello gitolite, this is gitolite@debian running gitolite3 v3.5.3.1-1-gf8776f5 on git 1.7.2.5

 R W    gitolite-admin
 R W    testing
Connection to debian closed.
```

But when trying to clone, it gives me the following error:

```
$ git clone ssh://gitolite@debian:2222/home/gitolite/repositories/gitolite-admin.git
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
FATAL: R any home/gitolite/repositories/gitolite-admin gitolite DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm trying to clone from *yasin@vonneumann* account. I uploaded this user RSA public key to *debian* server, renamed it to `gitolite.pub` and ran `gitolite setup -pk gitolite.pub` with no messages or errors. Then at *yasin@vonneumann* host I created a file at `~/.ssh/config` with the following content:

```
host debian
     user gitolite
     hostname debian
     identityfile ~/.ssh/gitolite
```

(I also copied `id_rsa` as `gitolite` at *vonneumann*)

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617672/git-clone-gitmyservergitolite-admin-fails) to be similar, but the answers did not work for me.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: About the close vote: *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming***. There are a bunch of other git/gitolite questions here.

Comment: Just for a record (as I got the same error, but for a different reason): make sure you actually **did not** put full key file name in gitolite's config file, as you need to strip the `.pub` extension. (This extension is added automatically by gitolite). So, for `keydir/id_rsa-yasin.pub` as authorized key, you need to use `id_rsa-yasin` in `config/gitolite.conf` when referring to it.

Comment: @Cromax Correct, but then you won't get the permissions shown on first command.

Comment: Well, I did — because of this "test" repo that comes with default config (SSH connection parameters, users, identity file were actually set correctly). So at first sight it appeared, that I have no R permissions to other configured repos and that surprised me. (I thought I didn't push config in the first place... but I did)... Then I noticed this *.pub damn thing. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `~/.ssh/config` file, you need to use the **[scp-like syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423667/6309)** for your ssh url:

```
git clone debian:gitolite-admin.git
```

With a config like:

```
host debian
  user gitolite
  hostname debian
  identityfile ~/.ssh/gitolite
  port 2222
```

And you are not supposed to specify the full path of the repo.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm; my SSH knowledge is very basic. Btw it's without ssh://, with this prefix it will not work: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known`.

Comment: @m0skit0 right, I have edited the answer to remove the `ssh://`, and add a link to another example of scp-like syntax.