# How does Gitolite check user read/write permissions?

Tags: git, permissions, gitolite

How does Gitolite check that current user has a write/read permission to given repository? Is this done by custom shell? If yes then how it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using the [ssh **forced command** mechanism](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858) to call the gitolite-shell script.

Gitolite register a user by adding to the ~git/ssh/authorized_keys a line similar to:

```
command="/devit_home/users/vobadm/gitpoc/ce7/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell gitoliteadm",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-for        warding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3N
```

The user id is derived directly from the name of the public key.

For more, see "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work/13320256#13320256)".

The read/write access are the [declared in the `gitolite.conf` file](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/admin.html#conf).

> Most of gitolite's power is in the `conf/gitolite.conf` file, which specifies detailed access control for repos.
>   Everything except adding users happens from this file.

```
    @staff              =   dilbert alice           # line 1
    @projects           =   foo bar                 # line 2

    repo @projects baz                              # line 3
        RW+             =   @staff                  # line 4
        -       master  =   ashok                   # line 5
        RW              =   ashok                   # line 6
        R               =   wally                   # line 7
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to write pure shell, my own, Git permission server which will work upon the Redis. It will be used as web app deployment tool, and I was bothering how to achieve that :)

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier will you use ssh or https access?

Comment: I think that it will be SSH only. But maybe in future it will be extracted as independent tool (now it is will be inside my [Puppet module](https://github.com/haulet/puppet-gitdeploy/)). Then maybe I add auth through HTTP also.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier ok, in that case, forced command is relevant. But you can link Gitolite with any mechanism able to authenticate a user (and call gitolite-shell). Gitolite is only an authoriation layer, it doesn't authenticate: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html. See another version of that explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339272/gitolite-can-connect-via-ssh-cant-clone/9340778#9340778.